# $route.reload bug in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

### Scroll bar is not shown while using $route.reload in angularjs

I want to reload the application while redirect one page to another page

So i have use proper code

```
            $location.path("/home");
            $route.reload();
```

The location changed also page is redirected. but the browser scroll bar is not shown. **if i doing force refresh the browser, then the scroll bar shown.** Why?

Actually I have fount a **bad solution** if i use `$window.location.reload();` instead of  `$route.reload();` then scroll bar shown.

**Why is this bad solution:**

`$window.location.reload()` is manually load the browser.

> But why scroll bar does not showing when i use  `$route.reload();`?